# Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n < 1$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^n=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n < 1$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^n=0$

I am trying but I am not getting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it this may help you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n \rightarrow c$, $0 \le c <1$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$ be small and $|x_n - c| < \epsilon < 1 -c $ for all $n$ large enough (larger than some $N $).

Then $0\le x_n < c+\epsilon < 1$.

So $0 \le x_n^n < (c+\epsilon)^n$.

$(c+\epsilon)^n\rightarrow 0$ so by sandwich theory $0 <= \lim x_n^n  < \lim (c+\epsilon)^n =0$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to reduce to the case where $x_n<1$ for all $n$ (why?).

It is clear that $\liminf x_n^n \geq0$.

Let $A=\lim x_n$. Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We have that, if $n>m$,

$$x_n^n< x_n^m.$$

It follows that
$$\limsup x_n^n \leq A^m.$$
Since $A<1$ and this holds for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ , it follows that $\limsup x_n^n \leq 0$. Therefore, $\lim x_n^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_n^n=\exp(n\ln x_n)$ and $\ln x_n$ converges to $\ln \lim x_n<0$

Hence $n\ln x_n$ goes to $-\infty$ and $\exp(n\ln x_n)$ goes to $0$.